# is there a canon explanation for how Santa can fit down a chimney?

Tags: canon, santa-claus

Santa is typically depicted as an obese man, or at least far heftier than a traditional chimneysweep.

He also is known to visit homes all around the world in a single night, and is typically credited with entry via chimney.

Given these two facts, he must be able to enter and exit through a chimney with very little delay (no extended crawling or squeezing).  Is there any canon explanation for how this can occur?

Comment: Magic.  He's a wiz—uh, Santa, and he uses magic.

Comment: scifi.stackexchange is for questions about existing works of fiction, i.e. about [*canon* in the sense of “A group of literary works that are generally accepted as representing a field.”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canon#Noun) There is no such group of literary works regarding Santa that I’m aware of; there is no “Santa canon”.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific work of fiction.

Comment: @Jeff: Man, I’m getting the festive spirit aren’t I? Also: Merry Christmas!

Comment: Santa is a probability wave, and chimneys act as a diffraction grating. Where you get peaks, presents, and troughs, no presents. Quantum effects of goodness and naughtiness affect the wave pattern. (bonus - gets around the need to travel). :)

Comment: I would say that the closest we can come to Santa Claus cannon is "Twas The Night Before Christmas".  
  
This poem makes it clear that Santa is tiny.  
  
Verse 39: "His droll little mouth..."  
  
Verse 43: "He had a broad face, and a little round belly"  
  
Verse 45: "He was chubby and plump, a right jolly old elf"  
  
OB SciFi/Fantasy: Santa is an elf.

Comment: @AdamZWasserman: a small mouth can be on a big man, and elves are not always small.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen this December, just to bug @PaulD.Waite :P

Comment: @MeatTrademark I WILL BURNINATE ALL THE PRESENTS AND MELT THE GODDAMN SNOW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Santa Claus Conquers the Martians](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut-hn7sFieE) is sci-fi. In the [movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oyrb-iSkpFE), Santa, and the children he rescued, escaped through a small air duct. When asked how he did it he said:

> "Well, well now, you wouldn't want me to tell my secret would you?"

So in *this* canon, there is no explanation. It's just a holiday miracle. **Happy holidays**.